# $2\alpha(\alpha-1)+\ln( \alpha)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined by : 
$$\forall x\in(0,+\infty)\quad f(x)=x+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x} $$

calculate $f^{-1}(1)$

let $\alpha \in(0,+\infty) $ such that $f^{-1}(1)=\alpha$ then
$f(\alpha)=1 \implies 2\alpha(\alpha-1)+\ln( \alpha)=0$
i'm stuck here i can't solve this equation i know that the solution is $1$
could we solve determinate inverse function of f i.e. $f^{-1}$

Comment: i think you can not calculate $$f^{-1}(x)$$ in an explicit form

Comment: that's what i thought

Comment: `i know that the solution is 1` That's correct, and $f(1)=1$ can be easily verified by direct substitution. This implies $f^{-1}(1)=1$ which answers the question as posted.

Answer (score 1):

For this special case, you can solve by elimination:
$$
\begin{align}
& 2\alpha(\alpha-1)+\log(\alpha)=0 \implies \log(\alpha)=2\alpha(1-\alpha) \\[2mm]
& \text{Let }\space g(\alpha)=\log(\alpha) \quad\&\quad h(\alpha)=2\alpha(1-\alpha) \\[2mm]
& \qquad \begin{cases} \alpha \,\in\, ]0,1[ &\Rightarrow\quad g(\alpha)=\log(\alpha) \lt0 \,,\space\space h(\alpha)=2\alpha(1-\alpha) \gt0 \\ \alpha \,\in\, ]1,+\infty[ &\Rightarrow\quad g(\alpha)=\log(\alpha) \gt0 \,,\space\space h(\alpha)=2\alpha(1-\alpha) \lt0 \end{cases} \\[2mm]
& \qquad \implies \color{red}{g(\alpha) \ne h(\alpha) \space\colon\space \alpha \,\in\, ]0,+\infty[\,-\,\{1\}} \\[2mm]
& \text{Remaining only }\space \color{red}{\alpha=1} \Rightarrow g(1)=\log(1)=0 \space\&\space h(1)=2\times1(1-1)=0 \\[2mm]
& \quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\color{white}{\text{.}}
\end{align}
$$
[image]